# Datapower- Reading the output context of Convert Query Params in next action

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am using **Convert Query** params to `XML` to convert from `JSON` to `JSONX`. The output of this action is stored in `Jsonx_Out`. I have a transform action with `Jsonx_Out` as input. Could anyone please help me out how I can read this context. I tried with `dp:variable(' var://context/Json_Out')`. This does not fetch the value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is the input context for your transform action, you can access it as you would any other XML input:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/json:object"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(Don't forget to define the json namespace.)

You should be able to access a context with `dp:variable` as you described.  I do notice you left out the 'x' in `Jsonx_Out` -- that may be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting JSONX?

Query Params outputs a XML so to get a param, eg. param1 from: http://server.com/uri?param1=HelloWorld

You'd use:

```
<xsl:variable name="param1">
    <xsl:value-of select="/request/args/arg[@name='param1']"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

The XSL var "param1" would then contain "HelloWorld"

Comment: The OP is correct here.  The "Convert Query Parameters to XML" action is used for more than just converting query parameters, but I guess IBM never got around to making its name more generic.  One of its uses, as described here, is to convert JSON input to JSONX.